# Software for Bluetooth headset

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, headset

I recently installed Windows 7 on my desktop and purchased a [Dell BH200 headset](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&sku=313-6220).

The problem is that the software that came with the bluetooth dongle (Bluesoleil 5) is fairly old and isn't compatible Windows 7.

Bluesoleil 6 is very expensive - is there something else I can do or use to get my headset working?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Widcomm drivers](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php) ?

Comment: Actually I just happened to have purchased BLuetooth USB adapters w/o any software as well. I tried using the Widcomm driver installer but they don't detect my adapters and won't proceed with the installation. ANy ideas?